# I need JUnit to pass only if 6 IllegalArgumentExceptions are thrown

Tags: java, exception, junit, illegalargumentexception

Each statement new `M#().multiply(-1)` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. Right now This passes if at least 1 exception is thrown. I need this to only pass if every single statement `new M#().multiply(-1)` throws an exception.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void test(){

    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("Integers must be positive");

    new M1().multiply(-1);
    new M2().multiply(-1);
    new M3().multiply(-1);
    new M4().multiply(-1);
    new M5().multiply(-1);
    new M6().multiply(-1);

}
```

I've been working on this for way too long now, please help.

Comment: Are these six distinct methods, or six distinct tests?  Once you throw *one* exception, you're done unless you retry the method - and you'll keep getting the same exception unless you vary your input.

Comment: 2 things: You are not following Unit testing correctly. You should write a test for every M# class and test all of them, expecting the exception. And you're using Exceptions wrongly. When an exception is thrown, it stop the code flow, so if one of the M# class throw an exception, all M# classes after it will not be called (in other words only the first M# statement will be executed in your test). But if you're not willing to recode, @manouti answers resolves your problem...

Comment: What does your M[1-6] classes look like?  Are they all inheriting from one another?  If you shared a simple implementation of one or two, we could tell you how to test it more *effectively*.

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think a unit test should do this. You can simply create 6 tests, each creating a different class object and expecting an exception.

Yet still, for this situation, you can catch the `IllegalArgumentException`s and count how many times they occur:

```
int exceptionCount = 0;
try {
    new M1().multiply(-1);
} catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    exceptionCount++;
}
try {
    new M2().multiply(-1);
} catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    exceptionCount++;
}
...
Assert.assertEquals(exceptionCount, 6);
```

Comment: Your answer is satisfactory to the OP's needs, but I strongly discourage this sort of approach when writing tests.

Comment: Its for an assignment and thats what the prof wants I guess